# Blender to Unity, vertex smoothing

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, blender

I have an object in blender that has sharp corners, and easily distinguishable faces, exactly what I want. However, when I place it in Unity all of the vertices smooth out, and it is impossible to see what you are looking at. How do I get the same object that I have in Blender to show up in unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tackled here
[blender-normal-smoothing-import-problem](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/294558/blender-normal-smoothing-import-problem.html)

Also you can calculate the normals on import via 'Smoothing angle' which will edge break/phong break based on the angles

Comment: @Flotolk Have you already noticed http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions would be nice to have you there.